# Anypoint studio is getting closed unexpectedly while opening anypoint exchange

Tags: crash, mule-studio

I have installed Anypoint studio (5.4.1) on my windows 7 64 bit machine with 4 gb of ram. When I try to use exchange (creating project from template or searching exchange to install connectors ) in the studio it crashes unexpectedly. [Here](http://forums.mulesoft.com/storage/attachments/901-hs-err-pid6116.txt) is the log report. I am running jdk 1.8.0_72. All software that I installed are 32 bit.

In the crash report, it says problematic frame in webkit.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Solved finally. I found that, in log file it says problem with frame in webkit.dll in Apple Application Support folder. I have Quicktime Player and Apple application support installed in my machine. I uninstalled the  Quicktime Player and Apple application support and it is working. I am able to explore the exchange in studio now.